# add values in first empty column within a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to add the values originated from my command within the for loop in the empty columns of data_frame_2. It must be added on the first empty column in sequence, so each iteration will fill the next empty column.

```
for (product in products) {
condition_1 <- datasets[[product]]$price >= "450"
condition_2 <- datasets[[product]]$price < as.character(450 + 30)
subset_data_frame <- datasets[[product]][condition_1 & condition_2, ]
data_frame_2[, "next_empty_column"] <- colMeans(subset_data_frame)
writeLines(".", sep = "")
} #1
```

where data_frame_2 would be: so column with head3 should be filled on the first round of the loop, head 4
on the second, consecutively.

```
 head 1  head 2  head 3 head 4 head 5
```

row 1   a      b      NA      NA      NA
row 2   c      d      NA      NA      NA
row 3   e      f      NA      NA      NA
row 4   g      h      NA      NA      NA

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Fala Ana blz, eu te ajudo mais amanhã mas basicamente sem dados para um exemplo é difícil te ajudar

Comment: If you compare your price to a character (i.e. `"450"`), the code is probably not doing what you think it is.